# e2e protractor test: getAttribute('value') return empty value running on jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, protractor, angularjs-e2e, getattribute

I'm writing a protractor test that check the value of an input type field.

**Code in the Test Page:**

```
expect(logPage.logFileSizeField.getAttribute('value')).toBe(logFileSizeDeafault)
```

**Object Page code:**

```
this.logFileSizeField = element(by.css('input[name="logFileSizeField"]'));
```

The test run correct localy (so I'm sure the element is found) but when it runs on jenkins it fails because the value returned from the getAttribute('value'); is empty.

Error from jenkins:

Error Message

> Expected '' to be '1048576'.

Stacktrace

```
Error: Failed expectation
   at [object Object].<anonymous>(/usr/src/app/tests/e2e/log/log.spec.js:43:64)
   at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd/index.js:94:14
```

Comment: I do the same in other tests that run correctly localy and on Jankins so i dont understand what could be the problem..

Comment: The app you are running the tests locally and in Jenkins has the same data? Try checking manually what is happening in Jenkins. Another thing I would try is pulling the getting element value part out of the expect and use `then()`, outputting the value to console (or even taking a screenshot) and running the expect, all withing that `then().

Comment: After hour on that i think the prolem is that the data i need is read from a file. Probably the fs.existSync() doesnt work